# Problems with the SAGA Next Gen Tool "Resampling Filter"

Tags: qgis, saga, resampling

When running the Saga Next Gen tool "**Resampling-Filter**" I get the error message:

> failed: could not find a suitable import driver**" and "**[Import
> Raster] Execution failed (less than 1 millisecond) [Error] executing
> tool: Import Raster

I have already tried different Saga versions (also the latest one: **9.2.0** (as of 10/30/2023). I am working with QGIS version **3.22.7**. I have also worked with another version to solve the problem. Do any of you have similar problems or know the problem?

I did the installation correctly and also changed to the new "SAGA" folder under "Options->Data provider" when I installed a new SAGA version. The SAGA folder is also correctly displayed to me, under the processing tools. Most of the other SAGANG tools work as well. "Fill sinks" unfortunately does not work either.